# Docuaurus having both side bar and burger menu on screen at once

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

When you reduce the width of a Docusaurus site below 996px the sidebar becomes a burger menu in the nav bar.

**Goal:** We want that burger menu to be shown on all pages regardless of the size of the screen.

Along with, when the screen is above 996px the sidebar should also be shown.

**Remarks:** Our landing page is a react page and should not have the side bar but we need it to have the burger menu in the nav bar.

Comment: You probably need to adjust some css code. It is hard to give any help without more information/code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution since this post ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want that "burger icon", that shows/hides the sidebar, to `always` be displayed.

So go to your `custom.css`, usually locate in `./src/css/custom.css` and add the following:

```
@media (min-width: 996px) {
    .navbar__toggle {
        display: inherit;
    }
}
```

---

**OBSERVATION**

I don't known if this answer will help you with the last part "Our landing page [..] need it to have the burger menu in the nav bar."

Comment: It doesn't works. Its displays the burger icon, but the menu is not displayed. Seems to be something hardcoded in JS...